# What's the extent of Apocalypse's abilities?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, marvel

Apocalypse claimed to possess many abilities

> that he collected from the various mutants he transferred his soul into over many lifetimes.

What are his original power(s), and what has he collected over time?

Answer (score 7):

#### The soul- or power-napping version of Apocalypse is a creation of Hollywood. It makes his power description easy enough for the average viewer to understand, and makes it clear that he has a head start of a few thousand years over any mutant in the series. It may also be hyperbole on his part, to keep anyone from recognizing that his abilities may have technological augmentations.

- In the cinematic universe, he is virtually immortal and can absorb the mutant abilities of anyone whose body he is transferred into. As such, his abilities are vast and apparently limitless. If he has an origin similar to the comic version, he was born virtually immortal and had complete control over his own molecular structure. Even without this, we see in the movie that he has been transferred into the body of a mutant with enhanced healing, and that he survived in this body for thousands of years.
- In the comics, **[En Sabah Nur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse_%28comics%29)** was born immortal, with the ability to control his physical abilities, giving him superhuman strength, resilience and durability. After discovering and exposing himself to extraterrestrial technology said to have belonged to the star-gods, the Celestials, he augmented himself further, increasing his abilities and allowing him to effectively utilize any mutant ability he could conceive of. Being of super-intelligence, he could conceive of quite a bit.

Wikipedia's entry on his powers includes:

> - The character has total control over the molecules of his body, enabling him to alter his form as it suits him, such as allowing his body to become extremely malleable and flexible or change his size, enhance his physical abilities, transform his limbs into weapons, wings, or jets, regenerate from fatal injuries, adapt his body to apparently any disease or hostile environment, as well as give himself virtually any superhuman power. (As seen in X-Factor #68, 1991)
> - He is also able to project and absorb energy, in addition to displaying capacities for telepathy and telekinesis. Apocalypse is also capable of technopathy, able to directly interface with the various technologies he has at his disposal. Thanks to the aid of his mutant abilities, special "regeneration" chambers, and changing bodies, Apocalypse has made himself effectively immortal.

Like his cinematic counterpart, Apocalypse appears to have nearly-limitless ability and power, sufficient enough to hold entire super-teams at bay. He typifies the Omega Level Mutant, a being whose powers make it possible for him to extinguish all life on Earth. With the ability to dominate both the physical realm and the mental one, he is a threat to anyone who tries to confront him and most likely sure to win. His only weakness is his overwhelming ego, and inability to conceive of someone who could be a threat to him.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In this struggle against the X-Men, in a weakened state, Apocalypse managed to defeat the entire lineup and escaped relatively unscathed. At his peak of ability, the X-Men would have been no match at all.

Comment: "he has a head start of a few thousand years over any mutant in the series" I don't think that's accurate as he was buried alive for most of the time and didn't have the opportunity to steal other powers.

Comment: He was buried alive in 3600BC but it was mentioned a few times that he is tens of thousands of years old.